# Lecturer asks for argument for re-submission

Tags: computer-science, lecturer, projects, assessment

Our group submitted part 1 of an assignment a few hours before the deadline, only to realise one of our links to the a piece of work was incorrect.

As soon as we found out, we emailed him explaining the situation and asking if there were consequences and if so what would they be.

He replied asking what we think should be done; arguments for and against re-submitting in our case from the perspective a university assignment and as a deliverable to a client.

How could I reply?

Comment: If you were a client and received a promised product with errors in it, what would you expect to be done?

Comment: @Harry if it was one error and small, I don't think I'd let it affect my judgement. If it was multiple times, I wouldn't have regard them in a positive light.

Comment: @Harry Also, if they approached you soon after you received it, rather than you finding out myself and then getting annoyed/confused, would this affect your judgement?

Comment: Corrigenda are quite common in academia when it comes to publications. Regarding the university assignment, whether a re-submission is accepted or not depends on the lecturer. You could highlight that you understand the difficulties, e.g. if he allow you to re-submit the assignment, others could ask for the same and he would have to accept this to be fair. Saying this, you could argue that maybe a cirrigendum could be okay because it is the scientific way of correcting mistakes.

Comment: @FuzzyLeapfrog would he allow others to re-submit or give the same consequences to other groups who did the same? If we didn't add to our work and instead simply corrected the link, whereas other groups may take this as a chance to make a few additions, would this be fair?

Comment: I see, you understand the dilemma, @Hawwa. There was a deadline. The deadline has passed. Extending the deadline for one group, allowing changes of any kind, ... open the doors for unequal treatment. Maybe he wanted you to realize this problem.

Comment: @FuzzyLeapfrog hmm yes. I understand all the points. He could either accept the old submission and this would mean one deliverable wasn't marked or was penalised. However, it would also lead to a discussion on penalties, what are they and when are they applied

Comment: So, perhaps the most crucial difference is that you currently have an opportunity to fix a mistake. That isn't always an option.

Comment: I understand it from the point of view of a teacher too, I tutor younger kids and homework problems are part of that. As a tutor, I ignore the first time, I teach/suggest to them what they could have done and expect them to follow these next time. In this case it's about applying the rule to everyone. Or does he just state that he'll review on a case-by-case basis?

Comment: @Harry sure, and in other situations this could be associated with financial implications

Comment: I'm interested to know what you'd do as a Lecturer

Comment: I would allow the correction because you've realized the error, it can be corrected with little effort, and failing to correct it sounds like it could invalidate otherwise well-done work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like the lecturer is trying to use the incident as a learning opportunity, aka **[teachable moment](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teachable_moment)**. He is asking you to argue your case in order to get you to think about the implications of your request so that you will learn a valuable lesson unrelated to the specific topic of the assignment. Probably he is reasoning that the current low-stakes situation is an excellent time to learn this lesson because the consequences of making a mistake are not large; by being a bit harsh or annoying now, he can teach you something that is likely to save you much more severe consequences at some later time in your life.

To clarify, I'm not expressing an opinion about whether making such a demand of you is a good idea, but I suspect that this is the reasoning motivating the lecturer's request.

As for how to reply, I suggest just following the lecturer's instructions and coming up with the best arguments you can. I could offer more specific advice, but I think that would defeat the purpose of what the lecturer is hoping you'd do, which is to think about this issue yourself. (Nor do I think there is a universally correct answer, for that matter.) And again to clarify, by saying this I don't mean to imply that there's anything wrong with you coming here to ask the question, but I sincerely think you're better off coming up with your own answers. Good luck!

Comment: yes that was the intention, and I sent a reply!